# Pre-Checking Radiobutton on condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Simple Question.

I have a variable called `gender` that is set previously.

I have 3 radio-buttons in a fieldset

```
<fieldset id={"input_gender_radio"}>
              &emsp;
              <input type="radio" value="0" id="male"
                     onChange={changeGender} name="gender"/>
              <label htmlFor="male"> Männlich</label>
              &emsp;
              <input type="radio" value="1" id="female"
                     onChange={changeGender} name="gender"/>
              <label htmlFor="female"> Weiblich</label>
              &emsp;
              <input type="radio" value="2" id="nonbinary"
                     onChange={changeGender} name="gender"/>
              <label htmlFor="nonbinary"> Nichtbinär</label>
          </fieldset>
```

I have a change-Handler

```
const changeGender=(e)=>{
  setGenderState(e.target.value);
}
```

and the State-constant

```
const [genderedit, setGenderState] = useState(gender);
```

How do I pre-check one of these radio-buttons conditioned on the variable `gender` when opening the webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Javascript:

```
if(gender == 0){
   document.queryselector("#male").checked = true;
}else if(gender == 1){
   document.queryselector("#female").checked = true;
}else if(gender == 2){
   document.queryselector("#nonbinary").checked = true;
}
```

Easy :)

Answer (score -1):

Just insert the `checked="checked"` attribute in the `input` tag.

```
<fieldset id={"input_gender_radio"}>
              &emsp;
              <input type="radio" value="0" id="male"
                     onChange={changeGender} name="gender" checked="checked"/>
              <label htmlFor="male"> Männlich</label>
              &emsp;
              <input type="radio" value="1" id="female"
                     onChange={changeGender} name="gender"/>
              <label htmlFor="female"> Weiblich</label>
              &emsp;
              <input type="radio" value="2" id="nonbinary"
                     onChange={changeGender} name="gender"/>
              <label htmlFor="nonbinary"> Nichtbinär</label>
          </fieldset>
```

Comment: Hi Guiherme, can you provide more information about what you want to do?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I dont want and need :)